# Is this noramal that on event in jquery does not work out when I send data to a function during on event, then how can I fix that?

Tags: javascript

Why on event in j-query does not work? It just work one time.

I want to move data to another block when on event in j-query work, so I made  arrays and when 'click' event occur, I move data to another array and execute function that is named 'showList' 
but it work just one time 
I want to know why this click event work just one time

```
function(dataList){
            var arrayNum=[];
            var arrayNumDown =[];

            //up
            var length = Math.floor(Math.random()*5+1);

            var list = "<div>";
            for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
                list+="<div class=number>";
                list+="<span>5523-1134-112"+i+"</span>";
                list+="<img class=imageA src=../image/x.png.png style=width:10px; height:10px;></div>";
                arrayNum.push("5523-1134-112"+i);
            }
            list+="</div>";
            $('#numbers').html(list);


            //down
            var Dlength = Math.floor(Math.random()*4+1);
            var ul="<ul>";
            for(var i=0; i<Dlength; i++){
                ul+="<li><input type=checkbox name=listCheck class=checkArr> <span id=spa"+i+">"+"2311-223-111"+i+"</span></li>";
                arrayNumDown.push("2311-223-111"+i);
            }
            ul+="</ul>";
            document.querySelector("#contents").innerHTML = ul;



            $('#numbers').on('click','.imageA',function(){

                var val =$(this).prev().text();

                for(var i=0; i<arrayNum.length; i++){
                    if(arrayNum[i]==val){
                        alert(i);
                        arrayNum.splice(i,1)
                        arrayNumDown.push(val);
                        console.log(arrayNumDown);
                        showList(arrayNum,arrayNumDown);

                    }
                }
            })

            $('.checkArr').on('click',function(){

                var val=$(this).next().text();

                for(var i =0; i<arrayNumDown.length; i++){
                    if(arrayNumDown[i]==val){
                        arrayNumDown.splice(i,1);
                        arrayNum.push(val);
                        console.log(arrayNum);
                        showList(arrayNum,arrayNumDown);

                    }
                }

            })

        }
}

function showList(arrayNum,arrayNumDown){
    var list = "<div>";
    for(var i=0; i<arrayNum.length; i++){
        list+="<div class=number>";
        list+=arrayNum[i];
        list+="<img src=../image/x.png.png style=width:10px; height:10px; id=x"+i+"></div>";
    }
    list+="</div>";
    $('#numbers').html(list);


    var ul="<ul>";
    for(var i=0; i<arrayNumDown.length; i++){
        ul+="<li><input type=checkbox name=listCheck id=chk"+i+"> <span id=spa"+i+">"+arrayNumDown[i]+"</span></li>";
    }
    ul+="</ul>";
    document.querySelector("#contents").innerHTML = ul;


}
```

Comment: Does it empty the `arrayNum` or `arrayNumDown` arrays in the first loop, so that the loop is empty on the next run? Maybe that's the problem. What error does it give?

Comment: there is the error message but click event just work one time when i cilck image or check box next time , click event does not work

Answer (score 0):

When you add the listener with `.on("click")`, it will only add it to the elements already available. When you dynamically add new elements, you need to add the listeners to those element after that.

The other option is to add the listener to the **parent** element and limit it with the selector variable to the wanted elements. This way it will work also on dynamically created elements:

```
$('#contents').on('click','.checkArr',function(){
```